# RPI4 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Switch between headless and hdmi mode without any changes

Tags: boot, 20.04, hdmi, raspberrypi, headless

I've installed **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** on my fresh Raspberry Pi 4.
The OS is configured to boot to **desktop** (xubuntu) and **autologin** is enabled.

The Pi should boot **either** with an HDMI cable plugged in or in headless mode when no monitor is connected. For the former, no changes are needed, as this is the default behaviour. However, the PI will not boot without further changes if no HDMI cable is plugged in.

**This seems to be the problem**: *if no screen is connected at boot then a display device is not created. Without a display device the GUI desktop does not start so any program that requires GUI will not start. Other RPi models did not have that issue because they would fall back to composite mode if no HDMI was connected. The RPi4 has composite mode disabled by default so no display device is created.*

**Following solutions are suggested**:

- using `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in order to force hdmi
- setting default resolution with e.g. `hdmi_mode=82` and a group with `hdmi_group=2`

**This gives the following** `config.txt`

```
[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin
max_framebuffers=2
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82

start_x=1
gpu_mem=256
```

This configuration allows the Pi to boot in **headless** mode. Everything seems to work fine. Using `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` will result in **nothing** being displayed on a monitor even if it is plugged in before the boot process. Nothing is displayed and the Pi **does not** boot completely! If you remove the line from config.txt, everything works fine again with monitor, but the Pi no longer boots headless.

I also tried using `[EDID=*]` **during** the boot to **check** if a monitor is present and set `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`  or `0`accordingly:

```
[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin
max_framebuffers=2       
start_x=1
gpu_mem=256

hdmi_force_hotplug=1
[EDID=*]
hdmi_force_hotplug=0
[all]
```

Unfortunately, this **does not** solve the problem either. With this setting, the PI **always** boots **completely**, but always in **headless** mode - even if a monitor is connected. At the beginning, the Pi start screen appears briefly on the monitor, but then **nothing** is displayed. Activation by clicking the return key several times also fails.

I know that for sure, the hint will come that I should use Raspbian. I would still like to solve the problem with Ubuntu.

Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Firstly are your changes going into /boot/firmware/config.txt?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 20.10 on a RPI4 and a CM4 and have no issues in running headless or not.  I suspect its your start_x line..  Try commenting it out and retying..  You really don't need any of the hdmi_force_hotplug

Comment: Yes changes are going into /boot/firmware/config.txt. Ok thanks for the hint! I will remove start_x and going to try it again

Comment: Without start_x i'm not able to access the camera module, which is required. Sry should have give this information before!

Comment: Yes that makes sense.   Which means by the sound of things that if you are using the camera module you must have a display.     Fascinating dependancy for a camera.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the start_x configuration item is forcing a dependancy on a display.  The work around is to attach the camera module to a VNC session.

This URL contains a guide to configuring your PI to do exactly that..

https://www.hackster.io/sridhar-rajagopal/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera-headless-setup-tips-37903c

Comment: I will definitely try that out, thanks! Interestingly, it works with start_x=1 in headless mode on my PI3 with Ubuntu 18.04. Isn't that strange? Or is it because of the combination of Ubuntu 20.04 and Pi4?

Comment: if your statement is true, how can it be that using start_x and hotplug=1 allows to boot fully and access the camera without any error?

Comment: Hi! before i wanted to through the tutorial you mentioned, I removed all the camera stuff from my code and commented start_x out in the config. This didn't change anything. Pi only boots with hdmi plugged in but not without

Comment: When it doesn’t boot does it leave any error logs in /var/logs to say why it didn’t ?

Comment: Found out, that everything works fine when using hdmi_force_hotplug and the HDMI port=0. It does not work when using hdmi port=1. Strange, tought that they are similar:D

Answer (score 2):

Source: [ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2451011)

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

hdmi_force_hotplug=1

hdmi_group=1 # 1 does not seem to work(however **0** looks like it's working)

hdmi_mode=16
```

On a Raspberry Pi 4, this appears to correct the problem. The Pi 4 booted at least twice with the HDMI cable unplugged during power-on.