# how to enable headless operation on an Ubuntu 22.04 desktop running on a Raspberry PI without screen

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, headless

I've tried to follow:

[RPI4 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: Switch between headless and hdmi mode without any changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322760/rpi4-and-ubuntu-20-04-lts-switch-between-headless-and-hdmi-mode-without-any-cha)

but it doesn't seem to work. The RPi fails to boot.

My goal is to be able to connect via Anydesk or something equivalent and get access to a desktop environment even though no screen are attached.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server?  or something else?  ie. please be specific as to what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you installed (*the link you refer to covers Xubuntu; so was it a flavor of 22.04?*)

Comment: "*...it doesn't seem to work*" and "*...fails to boot*" are, unfortunately, much too vague to offer useful advice. SOMETHING must have happened when you rebooted. Lights flash, screen text, cursor blinking, etc. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467873/edit) to detail that experience -- those little details are important troubleshooting clues.